# Viewing and capturing real time values of Tachometer measuring instrument on television set and computer monitor in Aircraft and Automobiles

Tags: aircraft-systems, measurement

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachometer

https://patents.google.com/patent/DE2500376A1/en

Is it possible to view and capture real time values of a Tachometer in Aircrafts, Automobiles, Spacecrafts, Rockets etc measuring speed (RPM) using wired, wireless or CCTV technology on television set or computer monitor?

Scenarios

1 Aircraft - Tachometer interfaced wired/wireless with the television set or computer monitor - Larger screen display taking into account all security aspects inside the cockpit of the aircraft. Viewing the Aircraft's speed in miles/hour or kms/hour in real time.

Aircraft include Aeroplane, Helicopter, Fighter planes etc.

2 Automobiles - Tachometer interfaced wired/wireless with the television set or  computer monitor - Larger screen display fixed inside the passengers back seat of the four wheeler private owned vehicle viz Cars, Jeeps. Viewing the speed of the vehicle by the passenger in miles/hour or kms/hour in real time.

This includes the driverless vehicles.

Comment: Like, mounting a GoPro to film the instrument continuously? That's straightforward. Converting those images to a stream of data would certainly be possible, but well outside the scope of this site. What end result are you hoping to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With modern automobiles (that is, after OBDII was introduced in the 1990s), it is trivially simple. You just need a Bluetooth OBDII reader (about $15 on Amazon, eBay, &c) and an application like Torque: https://torque-bhp.com/wiki/Main_Page

With most if not all light aircraft, it would be difficult, since the engines & instruments were developed long before modern electronics. You'd have to install additional sensors to pick up the data, which would probably be expensive, and might violate various regulations.

Comment: Would be cheap to do in an experimental...

Comment: @jamesqf It should be trivial to do if the aircraft has a glass cockpit (electronic, computerized avionics).

Comment: Most *new* light aircraft now have a G1000 (or I think one another altiernative), which makes it as easy as in a car.

Comment: @nick012000: But what percentage of GA aircraft are new enough to have a "glass cockpit"?  (I think upgrading older ones falls under the heading of non-trivial, no?)  Even then, do all the G1000 or similar units allow external devices to capture their data?  From the Wikipedia article, it seems like an extra-cost feature on high-end units: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garmin_G1000#GSD_data_aggregator